# Bootstrap with rbinom in R takes too long to run

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap, bernoulli-probability

I have been running bootstraps with rbinom for loops in R, but they take too long to run.

I want to perform the bootstrap on a dataset with 1,500,000 rows.

I want to resample the rows and for each of the resampled rows

1. rbinom two probabilities ('prob1' & 'prob2') into 0's and 1's ('prob1_ber' & 'prob2_ber')
2. add new column 'paired' with the combined outcome of step 1
3. rbinom the unique combinations of the columns 'paired' and 'positive' into 0's and 1's ('prob_final')
4. calculate 'pair_FPR' and 'pair_TPR'

This is what my code looks like:

```
library(boot)

#making example data
set.seed(1)
d2 <- data.frame(prob1=runif(n=1500000, min=1e-50, max=.9999999999),
                 prob2=runif(n=1500000, min=1e-44, max=.9999999989),
                 Positive=sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1500000))

#making bootstrap function
function_1 <- function(data, i){
  d2<-data[i,]
  
  d2$prob1_ber <- rbinom(nrow(d2), 1, d2$prob1) #bernoulli 1 or 0
  d2$prob2_ber <- rbinom(nrow(d2), 1, d2$prob2) #bernoulli 1 or 0
  
  d2$paired <- ifelse(d2$prob1_ber == 1 & d2$prob2_ber == 1, '11',
                      ifelse(d2$prob1_ber == 0 & d2$prob2_ber ==0, '00',
                             ifelse(d2$prob1_ber == 1 & d2$prob2_ber ==0, '10',
                                    ifelse(d2$prob1_ber == 0 & d2$prob2_ber ==1, '01', NA)))) 
  
  d2$prob_final <- ifelse(d2$paired == '00',d2$prob1_ber, NA) #if both negative then negative
  
  for (i in which(d2$paired =='11' & d2$Positive==1)) {
    d2$prob_final[i] <- rbinom(1,1,0.9)
  }
  for (i in which(d2$paired =='11' & d2$Positive==0)) {
    d2$prob_final[i] <- rbinom(1,1,0.5)
  }
  for (i in which(d2$paired =='01' & d2$Positive==1)) {
    d2$prob_final[i] <- rbinom(1,1,0.8)
  }
  for (i in which(d2$paired =='01' & d2$Positive==0)) {
    d2$prob_final[i] <- rbinom(1,1,0.1)
  }
  for (i in which(d2$paired =='10' & d2$Positive==1)) {
    d2$prob_final[i] <- rbinom(1,1,0.7)
  }
  for (i in which(d2$paired =='10' & d2$Positive==0)) {
    d2$prob_final[i] <- rbinom(1,1,0.2)
  }
  
  pair_FPR <- sum(d2[which(d2$Positive==0),]$prob_final) / nrow(d2[which(d2$Positive==0),])*100
  
  pair_TPR <- sum(d2[which(d2$Positive==1),]$prob_final) / nrow(d2[which(d2$Positive==1),])*100
  
  return(c(pair_FPR, pair_TPR))
}


set.seed(1)
boot_out <- boot(d2, function_1, 1000)
print(boot_out)
```

This bootstrap takes too long to run (n=1000). Is there a way to make it faster?

Many thanks!

Comment: `Error in NROW(data) : object 'd2' not found`.  Also, you forgot to include `library(boot)`.  Please help us to help you by making your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. I now added library(boot) and an example dataset 

d2 <- data.frame(prob1=runif(n=150000000, min=1e-50, max=.9999999999),
                 prob2=runif(n=150000000, min=1e-44, max=.9999999989),
                 Positive=sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=150000000))

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: `n=150000000` sets `n` to 150 million, not 1.5 million.  Neither are "minimal"...

Comment: You are right, I changed it to n=1500000 now. Any idea on how to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good reason for the old saw about "if you're using R and thinking of using a `for` loop, there's probably a better way to do it".  I think this is a case in point.

You've given no context or description of your overall objective and I've not taken the time to *understand* your code.  I'm also confused about why you've taken advantage of R's vectorisation in some places, but not in others.

Also, I think the use of the `boot` library is a red herring.  What matters is the underlying performance of your function `function_1`.  Finally, I don't think there's any need to generate 150,000,000 obesrvations - or even 1,500,000 - to investigate underlying performance.

Hence, my attempt to improve your function is:

```
function_2 <- function(data, i){
  d2<-data[i,] %>% 
    mutate(
      prob1_ber=rbinom(nrow(.), 1, prob1), #bernoulli 1 or 0
      prob2_ber=rbinom(nrow(.), 1, prob2), #bernoulli 1 or 0
      paired=ifelse(prob1_ber == 1 & prob2_ber == 1, '11',
                      ifelse(prob1_ber == 0 & prob2_ber ==0, '00',
                             ifelse(prob1_ber == 1 & prob2_ber ==0, '10',
                                    ifelse(prob1_ber == 0 & prob2_ber ==1, '01', NA)))), 
      dprob_final=case_when(
        paired == '00' ~ prob1_ber,
        paired =='11' & Positive==1 ~ rbinom(1,1,0.9),
        paired =='11' & Positive==0 ~ rbinom(1,1,0.5),
        paired =='01' & Positive==1 ~ rbinom(1,1,0.8),
        paired =='01' & Positive==0 ~ rbinom(1,1,0.1),
        paired =='10' & Positive==1 ~ rbinom(1,1,0.7),
        paired =='10' & Positive==0 ~ rbinom(1,1,0.2)
    )
  )
  
  pair_FPR <- sum(d2[which(d2$Positive==0),]$prob_final) / nrow(d2[which(d2$Positive==0),])*100
  
  pair_TPR <- sum(d2[which(d2$Positive==1),]$prob_final) / nrow(d2[which(d2$Positive==1),])*100
  
  return(c(pair_FPR, pair_TPR))
}
```

And my test data is

```
N <- 15000
#making example data
set.seed(1)
d2 <- data.frame(prob1=runif(n=N, min=1e-50, max=.9999999999),
                 prob2=runif(n=N, min=1e-44, max=.9999999989),
                 Positive=sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1500000))
```

Note that the results of `function_1(d2, i)` will not be the same as the results of `function_2(d2, i)` because of the *order* in which random numbers are generated. (`function_2`  works from row 1 to row n in order, `function_1 works through rows in groups defined by` paired`and`positive`.)  However, I believe the distributional properties of the two functions will be the same.

So, to compare performance...

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  list=list(
         "f1"= function_1(d2, 1), 
         "f2"= function_2(d2, 1)
       ), 
  times=10
)
Unit: nanoseconds
 expr min lq mean median uq max neval
   f1   7  9 28.7      9  9 203    10
   f2   8  9  8.9      9  9  10    10
```

A mean relative reduction in execution time of 100 * (27.7 - 8.9) / 27.7 = 67.8%.  Relative performance may well depend on `N`, but I expect the benefit to increase with `N` because the benfits of vectorisation over looping should increase as `N` increases.

Bear in mind that using the tidyverse, whilst giving code that is usually easy to read and maintain, does not usually give the fastest execution times.  `data.table` and base R are usually superior.

I leave it to others to improve on my effort.  I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts! I agree that the for loops make the code slow. The difference between function_1 and function_2 is important. I aim to give the paired group (paired & Positive) a percentage of 0's and 1's. So for paired=01 & Positive=1 rbinom(0.8) I want about 80% of the rows to have 1's and 20% to have 0's. With function_2 this doesn't happen. Using your example data paired=01 & Positive=1 gives 1's for final_prob of all rows which is not what I would like to have. Maybe you know another way to give the group certain % of 0's and 1's now you understand the aim more? Many thanks